# Is created several dummy variable columns an effecient way to retrieve data?

Tags: mysql

Maybe I am not using the right terms, but I have been searching for this subject on the internet and I have not found much information.

Here's some background info;  I have a large database (around 5 million entries) and I have to do a lot targeting based on several different criteria.

So in my head (completely informal training in the ways of SQL) I thought it good to create several dummy columns giving it a value of 1 or 0.  That way when I do my search my where clause is searching for WHERE x=1 or y=1 or z=1.  I kind of view it as doing some of the work up front, I use UPDATE table SET column=1 WHERE variables (LIKE or =) 'blank'

Like I said I have not found much literature on this.  Therefore it does not appear to be standard operating procedures for SQL, but I am pretty sure this is a faster more efficient way of searching retrieving data than searching for text strings.  So I am wondering why people don't do this as a standard procedure?   Or maybe they do I don't know.

I know this is somewhat open ended and I apologize in advanced if I have bothered anyone with this question.  Also thank in advanced for anyone who can answer or give me some feed back.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be an efficient approach, especially if the goal is to return a matrix of "counts" of rows that meet specified criteria.

I've actually implemented this approach for a data warehouse system. (We didn't update the detail rows, we populated an "indicator" table from the detail table. We were primarily using the `0`/`1` indicator columns in queries that returned  SUM() aggregates on several of them, to return a set of counts by dimension. The WHERE clauses in those queries were on dimensions, not on the `0`/`1` indicator columns. (Obviously, the indicator columns were available for use in WHERE clause, and we did make use of them for that as well.)

The data was in the data warehouse was added/updated by a scheduled process (nightly) using an extract from production online system.  All of the detail data was loaded, but then we also created "summary" tables consisting of keys and integer values, which contained 0 and 1.

(Without those columns in the summary table, the SQL statement required to return the specified resultset was larger than the maximum size allowed for a SQL statement on the Teradata database we were using. That was the big reason we implemented the tables, but it was efficient.

The queries we were running were "rollup" type queries across a couple of dimensions, from very low level up to a high summary level (per day, per week, per month, per year) and (per tech, per manager, per district), and (per COE, per NPA, per State).

At the lowest levels, we had a whole lot of "zeros" we had to return, with a column for "technician dispatched within 1 "work" day AND ticket closed with success status same day as dispatch, and no repeat ticket submitted within 10 days", and another column the same except there was a repeat ticket within 10 days, etc.

We actually had the interface designed where one of the "cells" with a "count" in the display could be selected, and we'd return a report of the detail rows of that were included in that "count".

And there wasn't any literature about this approach back then either; I just figured out how to do it. Again, this was for a data warehouse, ad hoc query environment, with tens of millions of rows. We had an online window where the system had to be available (7AM to 7PM).

Comment: Thanks Spencer.  That's weird that there is not much literature on the subject it seems pretty logical to me.  Like you I just kind of figured it out.  I am also have an econometrics background so naturally I like dummy and categorical variables.  And now that you are mentioning it, I do see a lot of potential for reporting purposes with this method.

Comment: @user3548821: there's a tradeoff: additional time and space to calculate the "indicator" columns. We were basically pulling "all" rows for a month and a region, and we wanted a "count" of how many of them met some criteria: "red", "blue", "red and small", "red or blue", etc. The same rows were being counted multiple times, it wasn't efficient to get the counts individually with separate WHERE clauses; with one pass through all the rows we could effectively increment "counters" in the query using `SUM(indicator)` expressions.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are talking about simple search conditions (such as "salary > 10000"), then there is no advantage in performance for using separate variables.  In fact, they occupy space in a row and longer rows require more overhead.

Such flags could help for more complex conditions.  For instance, if you have complicated text comparisons, then precalculating the results might help performance.  Similarly, if the conditions require cross multiple tables, particularly with aggregations, then precalculated values can help.

The solution to your performance issue is probably indexes.  However, you don't provide enough information to determine if these will really help.

Comment: Thanks Gordon, and sorry for not provided enough info. They are complicated conditions, complicated text comparison and like you said there is also conditions across tables. I have tried indexing and this method of dummy variables is by far faster.